# Save Uploaded Image as PNG

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

In my Django app, Users can upload images. I want to save every uploaded image as a PNG. I've been trying to do this with PIL but it's not working. It still seems to be saving as the original image type (whatever the user uploaded it as). What am I doing wrong?

```
if form.cleaned_data['dataset_image']:
   # dataset.dataset_image = form.cleaned_data['dataset_image']
    name = 'dataset%s.png' % (dataset.id)
    size = (200, 200)
    try:
        im = Image.open(form.cleaned_data['dataset_image'])
        im.save(name, 'PNG')
        print "saved file: ", im
    except IOError:
        # dont' save the image
        pass
```

When I upload a jpg (that I want to convert to png), the print statement gives this: `saved file:  <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=628x419 at 0x107354F80>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The print statement refers to the `Image` object when you opened the file. It used the `JpegImagePlugin` class because it is a jpeg image. However, when you call the method `save()`, you save the image based on the extension of the requested filename, in this case, png.

Try this if you aren't convinced.

```
try:
    im = Image.open(form.cleaned_data['dataset_image'])
    im.save(name)
    png_img = Image.open(name)
    print "saved file: ", png_img        # it's more clean to print `png_img.format`
```

By the way, just calling `im.save(name)` will also do in this case, since `name` already has the extension and the method will figure out you want it in that format.

Comment: I just realised the irony of asking you to try something in a try statement.

Comment: aaah makes so much sense- thank you so much @Reti43 Glad to not have to 'try' something else!